# Invalid timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Just wondering why it happens:

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > Time.now.zone
=> "YEKT"

1.9.3-p327 :002 > Time.now.in_time_zone("YEKT")
ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone: YEKT
```

YEKT - is the timezone of my city(Yekaterinburg).

What the hell is going on? I'm setting up a project and trying to fix all tests, but can't fix this behavior. Or can I emulate another current timezone(without changing code ideally)?

Comment: why dont you just do `Time.now` if your Time.now.zone is already 'YEKT'

Comment: Here are some complicated rules for timezones, and it should be tested. Anyway, question is: Why module (Time) returns "YEKT" to me if it's not a valid timezone for another method of Time? And how can I fix it.

Comment: so if you can try this `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.collect(&:name)` this will return you the list which are allowed by to `in_time_zone` method. now Time.now.zone will return you system time zone. you can try any time which is in the list and it will work

Comment: Thanks, now I see that Time.now.zone returns system time zone. It's an answer for "why" :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why it happens(thanks @Athar):

Time.now.zone returns a system time zone, while `in_time_zone` works with strict list (`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.collect(&:name)`)

Workaround: You can specify your timezone that way:

```
TZ=UTC rails console

1.9.3-p327 :001 > Time.now.zone
=> "UTC"
```

"UTC" is a valid timezone, so everything works.

Comment: you can see all the supported timezones using `rake time:zones:all`

Answer (score 7):

These are the available timezones.

```
{
 "International Date Line West"=>"Pacific/Midway",
 "Midway Island"=>"Pacific/Midway",
 "American Samoa"=>"Pacific/Pago_Pago",
 "Hawaii"=>"Pacific/Honolulu",
 "Alaska"=>"America/Juneau",
 "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"=>"America/Los_Angeles",
 "Tijuana"=>"America/Tijuana",
 "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"=>"America/Denver",
 "Arizona"=>"America/Phoenix",
 "Chihuahua"=>"America/Chihuahua",
 "Mazatlan"=>"America/Mazatlan",
 "Central Time (US & Canada)"=>"America/Chicago",
 "Saskatchewan"=>"America/Regina",
 "Guadalajara"=>"America/Mexico_City",
 "Mexico City"=>"America/Mexico_City",
 "Monterrey"=>"America/Monterrey",
 "Central America"=>"America/Guatemala",
 "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"=>"America/New_York",
 "Indiana (East)"=>"America/Indiana/Indianapolis",
 "Bogota"=>"America/Bogota",
 "Lima"=>"America/Lima",
 "Quito"=>"America/Lima",
 "Atlantic Time (Canada)"=>"America/Halifax",
 "Caracas"=>"America/Caracas",
 "La Paz"=>"America/La_Paz",
 "Santiago"=>"America/Santiago",
 "Newfoundland"=>"America/St_Johns",
 "Brasilia"=>"America/Sao_Paulo",
 "Buenos Aires"=>"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
 "Montevideo"=>"America/Montevideo",
 "Georgetown"=>"America/Guyana",
 "Greenland"=>"America/Godthab",
 "Mid-Atlantic"=>"Atlantic/South_Georgia",
 "Azores"=>"Atlantic/Azores",
 "Cape Verde Is."=>"Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
 "Dublin"=>"Europe/Dublin",
 "Edinburgh"=>"Europe/London",
 "Lisbon"=>"Europe/Lisbon",
 "London"=>"Europe/London",
 "Casablanca"=>"Africa/Casablanca",
 "Monrovia"=>"Africa/Monrovia",
 "UTC"=>"Etc/UTC",
 "Belgrade"=>"Europe/Belgrade",
 "Bratislava"=>"Europe/Bratislava",
 "Budapest"=>"Europe/Budapest",
 "Ljubljana"=>"Europe/Ljubljana",
 "Prague"=>"Europe/Prague",
 "Sarajevo"=>"Europe/Sarajevo",
 "Skopje"=>"Europe/Skopje",
 "Warsaw"=>"Europe/Warsaw",
 "Zagreb"=>"Europe/Zagreb",
 "Brussels"=>"Europe/Brussels",
 "Copenhagen"=>"Europe/Copenhagen",
 "Madrid"=>"Europe/Madrid",
 "Paris"=>"Europe/Paris",
 "Amsterdam"=>"Europe/Amsterdam",
 "Berlin"=>"Europe/Berlin",
 "Bern"=>"Europe/Berlin",
 "Rome"=>"Europe/Rome",
 "Stockholm"=>"Europe/Stockholm",
 "Vienna"=>"Europe/Vienna",
 "West Central Africa"=>"Africa/Algiers",
 "Bucharest"=>"Europe/Bucharest",
 "Cairo"=>"Africa/Cairo",
 "Helsinki"=>"Europe/Helsinki",
 "Kyiv"=>"Europe/Kiev",
 "Riga"=>"Europe/Riga",
 "Sofia"=>"Europe/Sofia",
 "Tallinn"=>"Europe/Tallinn",
 "Vilnius"=>"Europe/Vilnius",
 "Athens"=>"Europe/Athens",
 "Istanbul"=>"Europe/Istanbul",
 "Minsk"=>"Europe/Minsk",
 "Jerusalem"=>"Asia/Jerusalem",
 "Harare"=>"Africa/Harare",
 "Pretoria"=>"Africa/Johannesburg",
 "Kaliningrad"=>"Europe/Kaliningrad",
 "Moscow"=>"Europe/Moscow",
 "St. Petersburg"=>"Europe/Moscow",
 "Volgograd"=>"Europe/Volgograd",
 "Samara"=>"Europe/Samara",
 "Kuwait"=>"Asia/Kuwait",
 "Riyadh"=>"Asia/Riyadh",
 "Nairobi"=>"Africa/Nairobi",
 "Baghdad"=>"Asia/Baghdad",
 "Tehran"=>"Asia/Tehran",
 "Abu Dhabi"=>"Asia/Muscat",
 "Muscat"=>"Asia/Muscat",
 "Baku"=>"Asia/Baku",
 "Tbilisi"=>"Asia/Tbilisi",
 "Yerevan"=>"Asia/Yerevan",
 "Kabul"=>"Asia/Kabul",
 "Ekaterinburg"=>"Asia/Yekaterinburg",
 "Islamabad"=>"Asia/Karachi",
 "Karachi"=>"Asia/Karachi",
 "Tashkent"=>"Asia/Tashkent",
 "Chennai"=>"Asia/Kolkata",
 "Kolkata"=>"Asia/Kolkata",
 "Mumbai"=>"Asia/Kolkata",
 "New Delhi"=>"Asia/Kolkata",
 "Kathmandu"=>"Asia/Kathmandu",
 "Astana"=>"Asia/Dhaka",
 "Dhaka"=>"Asia/Dhaka",
 "Sri Jayawardenepura"=>"Asia/Colombo",
 "Almaty"=>"Asia/Almaty",
 "Novosibirsk"=>"Asia/Novosibirsk",
 "Rangoon"=>"Asia/Rangoon",
 "Bangkok"=>"Asia/Bangkok",
 "Hanoi"=>"Asia/Bangkok",
 "Jakarta"=>"Asia/Jakarta",
 "Krasnoyarsk"=>"Asia/Krasnoyarsk",
 "Beijing"=>"Asia/Shanghai",
 "Chongqing"=>"Asia/Chongqing",
 "Hong Kong"=>"Asia/Hong_Kong",
 "Urumqi"=>"Asia/Urumqi",
 "Kuala Lumpur"=>"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur",
 "Singapore"=>"Asia/Singapore",
 "Taipei"=>"Asia/Taipei",
 "Perth"=>"Australia/Perth",
 "Irkutsk"=>"Asia/Irkutsk",
 "Ulaanbaatar"=>"Asia/Ulaanbaatar",
 "Seoul"=>"Asia/Seoul",
 "Osaka"=>"Asia/Tokyo",
 "Sapporo"=>"Asia/Tokyo",
 "Tokyo"=>"Asia/Tokyo",
 "Yakutsk"=>"Asia/Yakutsk",
 "Darwin"=>"Australia/Darwin",
 "Adelaide"=>"Australia/Adelaide",
 "Canberra"=>"Australia/Melbourne",
 "Melbourne"=>"Australia/Melbourne",
 "Sydney"=>"Australia/Sydney",
 "Brisbane"=>"Australia/Brisbane",
 "Hobart"=>"Australia/Hobart",
 "Vladivostok"=>"Asia/Vladivostok",
 "Guam"=>"Pacific/Guam",
 "Port Moresby"=>"Pacific/Port_Moresby",
 "Magadan"=>"Asia/Magadan",
 "Srednekolymsk"=>"Asia/Srednekolymsk",
 "Solomon Is."=>"Pacific/Guadalcanal",
 "New Caledonia"=>"Pacific/Noumea",
 "Fiji"=>"Pacific/Fiji",
 "Kamchatka"=>"Asia/Kamchatka",
 "Marshall Is."=>"Pacific/Majuro",
 "Auckland"=>"Pacific/Auckland",
 "Wellington"=>"Pacific/Auckland",
 "Nuku'alofa"=>"Pacific/Tongatapu",
 "Tokelau Is."=>"Pacific/Fakaofo",
 "Chatham Is."=>"Pacific/Chatham",
 "Samoa"=>"Pacific/Apia"
}
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: It's not an answer; Why module (Time) returns "YEKT" to me if it's not a valid timezone for another method of Time?

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple core extension for String so that I can ensure that I use rails-acceptable time zone names.

```
ruby 2.5
rails 5.2
```

define core extension

```
# app/lib/core_extensions/string.rb
module CoreExtensions
  module String
    def to_time_zone_name
      strip!
      return self if ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key?(self)

      ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.invert[self]
    end

    def valid_time_zone_name?
      to_time_zone_name.present?
    end
  end
end
```

set up core extension

```
# config/initializers/core_extensions.rb
String.include CoreExtensions::String
```

usage

```
"YEKT".valid_time_zone_name?
#=> false
"Tokyo".valid_time_zone_name?
#=> true
```

Hope this will be useful for somebody.